# SMPS Oscillating Output

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I designed a SMPS and made a PCB for it. It successfully can output **6.4V** on the output, but whenever any kind of load is attached to it, it starts oscillating for some reason. The following is the schematic and PCB layout.

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB]

**A few things I've noticed that may be a problem :**

- The voltage at the Vcc pin of the NCP1070 PWM is **7.4-7.5V** when the min is **7.8V** according to datasheet
- The reference voltage of the TL431AC is **1.25V** instead of the desired **2.5V** (this is because I assumed the voltage would be **12V** at the output prior of assembling the PCB)

These problems may effect the final output of the circuit, but I don't think they are the cause of the output oscillating.

Comment: Please always add links to the datasheets of used ICs. And draw the schematic such, that positive voltage are upper. Oscillation frequency, amplitude? In [datasheet of TL431AC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1704600845518&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) in figure 10-1 is an example of a comparator circuit. This is what U2 is doing in your SPMS, right? **Then C6 is IMHO useless**, IMHO remove it, it slows down the comparator with time constant of ca. 2 ms! (R4//R5 + C6) - together with the time constant of "T1, D6, C4, L1, C5" it could start to oscillate IMHO.

Comment: Where you got the schematic from? A source reference is required in this forum AFAIR. Is it figure 43 from [NCP1070 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1070-d.pdf)? Then my previous comment is wrong. Your transformator is [750871110](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/750871110?qs=AXuZnX5ayYT6iN42jV%252BxiA%3D%3D)? It states 5 V/10 V output - is it still ok with NCP1070P065? I found that TL431AC has 2.5 V ref, why 1.25 V? AFAIR from 30 years ago from colleagues, SMPS calculation is quite difficult and tedious. Your calculations of the values in your schematic?

Comment: The figure 43 from the NCP1070 datasheet was one of the schematics that influenced the design. The transformer has the same name but it's this one [link](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/würth-elektronik/750871110/2208834). The ref voltage is 1.25V because I expected 12V at the output but it's only 6.4V. All the passive component values were taken from example schematics. The only thing I did was simple calculations like the voltage divider.

Comment: Few things could explain the oscillations: 1) add a 1-nF cap. between the FB and GND pins of the controller, very closely located, 2) make sure the emitter of the opto goes to the IC ground pin and not elsewhere and 3) the output inductance is way too high in my opinion, drop it to 2.2 µH. As a side comment, the 1N4007 diodes you used for rectification purposes are not adapted, too slow. For \$D_7\$, you can chose a BAV21 and for the sec. diode \$D_6\$, use a Schottky if the reverse voltage is not too high, a S310 maybe.

Comment: What about the lower then usual ref voltage?

Comment: @TheButterMineCutter: The lower reference voltage is really weird - is the device defect? You could disconnect the SPMS from AC and feed about 13 to 15 VDC to J2. Now I would expect 2.5 V ref, 12 V cathode - by measuring check with a DSO, that it does not oscillate perhaps with some MHz? - just in case... do you have an other sample of a TL431AC?

Comment: I can't test the circuit by feeding it 13 to 15 VDC since I don't have the equipment. But in theory, that is what I was going for : I designed the voltage divider to output 2.5V when 12V is applied as input. What I'm thinking is to redesign the voltage divider to output 2.5V when 6.4V is at its input, thoughts? Yes, I have two spare ICs.

Comment: I think you may need a pullup resistor on your FB pin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another idea, why it could oscillate only with a load:

**The [transformator](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/750871110.pdf)** has a 5 V output coil (pins 7+9/12+14) and auxiliary 10V coil (pins 1/3).

But when you use the 5V coil for 12V (even ignoring D6), the auxiliary voltage will be (12 / 5) * 10 = 24 V! According the datasheet of NCP1070 maximum ratings table page 4 I_VCC is limited to **15 mA** only, but with 8.2 V of Vclamp top left in figure 3, there is 24 - 8.2 V over R3 of 560 Ohm = **28 mA, that is too much!**

So the chip stops pulsing, because VCC/IVCC increases too much!
IOVP 6.2 to 11.2 mA (page 7) stops the chip pulsing (page 7).

But why this does not happen even with no load?
Like others mentionned D6 and D7 should be fast (Shottky) diodes.
If there is no load, the pulse through D7 is very short. So the used slow diode (and slow Al C3?) just rectifies enough that the chip NPCP1070 works, but not exceeds the VCC limits.

As soon as a load is applied the pulse duration gets so long, that even the bad D7 charges the C3 so high, that the chips max. VCC (or IVCC) is exceeded and **the chip NCP1070 shuts down due to overload of IVCC**!

Until C3 is so much discharged, **that NCP1070 starts again**?
And then quickly get in the OVL (tOVP = 80 us) - **what is the frequency of your oscillation?**

R3 has to be fixed, perhaps make a voltage divider with R3a and R3b, that it has 7 : 5 ratio, and R3a//R3b = 560 Ohm?

D7 a shottky diode.

C3 is an Aluminum electrolyte capacitor? That is slow for the frequencies (IMHO). Use a Tantal C parallel, or better also a ceramic 100nF (or more) of any (bad = X7R) quality.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the suggestion you made and see if it works. I don't know the oscillation frequency since I don't have an oscilloscope. For R3, what resistance should I use to limit the current? I'd rather avoid making a voltage divider since I would need to manufacture another board. For the voltage divider of R5 & R4, do I redesign it and take into account that the Vcc is going to be 5V ~ 6.4V?

Comment: I bought once a [PicoScope DSO 2204A](https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/2000/picoscope-2000-overview), because this DSO is ok with less than 200 USD and for private usage, but check the measurement ground of the DSO - its the PC's ground/earth whose USB is connected to it! Without it is probably difficult to develop/measure/repair a SMPS properly.